# Unable to get exact result for CAML Query

Tags: caml-query, caml, caml-designer

- I am trying to execute below condition in REST , But OData in Rest
  doesn't support **null** . I would like to execute below condition in
  CAML Query and Pass to REST.
- Tried using CAML Query ,But I am getting mismatch result.

Can any one please do let me know who can make caml query for my below cnoditons

country=USA or UK or India or UAE or France AND ProductCategory=NULL AND Products!=NULL or Grains

Comment: https://www.u2u.be/software > U2U Caml Query Builder

Comment: Sir, Software's are not allowed .Could you please extend your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (replace your internal field name and field type)

```
 <And>
     <And>
        <Eq><FieldRef Name='Country'/><Value Type='Text'>USA</Value></Eq>
        <Or>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='Country'/><Value Type='Text'>UK</Value></Eq>
            <OR>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='country'/><Value Type='Text'>India</Value></Eq>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>UAE</Value></Eq>                
            </Or>
        </Or>
    </And>
    <And>
        <IsNull><FieldRef Name='ProductCategory' /></IsNull>
        <And>
                 <IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Product' /></IsNotNull>
                 <Neq>
                      <FieldRef Name='Product' />
                      <Value Type='Text'>Grains</Value>
                 </Neq>
        </And>
    </And>
</And>
```